# Service Life of a Flashback Arrestor

Tags: piping, safety, gas, valves

First of all, I would like to know about the service life of a [flashback arrestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashback_arrestor). In my laboratory, I got three flashback arrestors {WITTgas RF53N(1/4”NPT-F), Brass} from the ex-students who used those items in 2012 and already finished their graduation. I joined the laboratory in 2015. In this circumstance, I want to know if there is any possible way to check those flashback arrestor. All the flashback arrestors they used are for the premixed combustion in a Constant Volume Combustion Chamber. My purpose is also same. But I want to know first whether those flashback arrestors are dead or alive.

Comment: Can you find any tech sheets from the manufacturer? Typically those will list a warranteed or recommended lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manufacturer says this](http://2.wittgas.com/filepool/Datenblaetter/usa/armaturen/flashback_arrestor_rf53n_dn_nsk_nu_u_usa.pdf) about maintanence:

> - annual testing of the non-return valve, body leak tightness
>     and flow capacity is recommended
> - WITT is happy to supply special test equipment
> - Flashback Arrestors are only to be serviced by the
>     manufacturer; the dirt filter may be replaced by competent
>     staff

Given that you inherit this equipment and don't know how it was treated I would do the recommended testing, or have it done. I would likewise replace the dirt filter.
Contact Witt (or their sales rep/service partner) about these steps to get an idea if you can do this yourself, have it done by a technician in house or need external help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. After calling to WITT, they prescribe me to do the annual checkup